# CircularGauge - Simple binding does not work

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a CircularGauge with a range from 0 to 150.

Just for presentation I wanted to bind the current value to a random value. The property is changing but it does not affect the UI. Any ideas?

xaml:

```
    <Window x:Class="Gauge_3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Gauge_3"
        xmlns:gc="clr-namespace:CircularGauge;assembly=CircularGauge"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="auto" Width="auto">
    <Grid>
        <gc:CircularGaugeControl x:Name="cControl"
            GaugeBackgroundColor="LightGreen" MinValue="0" 
                                 VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                 MaxValue="150" Radius="150" RangeIndicatorRadius="130" 
                                 RangeIndicatorThickness="10"
                                 OptimalRangeStartValue="50" OptimalRangeEndValue="85"
                                 DialTextColor="Black"
                                 DialText="Produktion"
                                 DialTextOffset="30"
                                 ScaleStartAngle="-210" 
                                 ScaleSweepAngle="240"
                                 MajorTickColor="Transparent"
                                 MinorTickColor="Transparent"
                                 ScaleLabelForeground="Transparent"
                                 CurrentValue="{Binding PercentValue}"
                                 PointerLength="110"
            Background="Transparent"                                      ImageSource="images/AW_Logo.png"
                                 ImageSize="60,60"
                                 ImageOffset="80">
</gc:CircularGaugeControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

.cs file

```
    namespace Gauge_3
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaktionslogik für MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private Timer aTimer;

        private double _PercentValue = 120;
        public double PercentValue
        {
            get { return _PercentValue; }
            set { _PercentValue = value; this.OnPropertyChanged("PercentValue"); }
        }


        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            cControl.DataContext = this;
            aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000 * 2);
            aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
            aTimer.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void OnTimedEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Random rdPercent = new Random();
            PercentValue = rdPercent.Next(70, 145);
        }



        #region INotifyPropertyChanged members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }            
}
```

I´ve also tried to change the value by clicking a button, but nothing happened.

Comment: How are you setting DataContext on your view? Can you post your whole .cs and .xaml file?

Comment: cControl.DataContext = this;

Comment: Yes it does implement the INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: Ok, you have the minimum required boilerplate for your view/view model bindings. Please post your whole .cs code and .xaml code.

Comment: Thus other binded properties works? Can you bind a bool or something juste for test?

Comment: Yes normally this works also when I restart VS

Comment: Try to bind your datacontext to your window.

Comment: this works - but why???

Comment: Are you explicitly setting the DataContext of the CircularGaugeControl somewhere else?